# How to debug ASP.NET website hosted on IIS server (Godaddy)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I uploaded asp.net website from my local machine to server. I am getting some exceptions on server while the same exceptions are not reproducible at local machine. How can I debug website hosted on Server from the Visual studio installed on my local machine?

Comment: u can't do like that because when u started u r application on the server process get started on the server only for debugging u have to add which process to take for debugging but now u want to do in u r local machine where the process of server was not available

Comment: If you have a VPN access to the web server then you can do remote debugging using Visual Studio. If you don't have VPN access but you can RDP into the server then you can install Visual Studio (if not installed) into the server and do the debugging from there by attaching the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems hosting my asp.net application on godaddy, I had all kinds of compatibility and database issues where I was getting one error after another after 1 week of troubleshooting.

Instead, I uploaded to somee.com and it was almost seamless.  The only issue was that I had to script the SQL databases manually, I was getting errors uploading the ldf and mdf files automatically.

To upload is now very easy, you just publish on visual studio and update the SQL scripts on the somee server and works every time.